# xml transformation to xml with xslt template

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an xml file like this. This have may iterations of  i got a requirement to transform this xml file into an another xml file with a particular way as displayed below. So for this reason i need to generate the xslt file to covert the xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test%20schema%20from%20editor.xsd">
 <Measures>
  <Project>SMFC4B0</Project> 
  <WorkProduct>Algo Integration Test</WorkProduct> 
  <Date>41725</Date> 
  <M14>100</M14> 
  <M99>10</M99> 
  <M102>0</M102> 
  <M100>100</M100> 
 </Measures>
 <Measures>
 <Project>ARS 400</Project> 
  <WorkProduct>System Test</WorkProduct> 
  <Date>41725</Date> 
  <M14>100</M14> 
  <M99>10</M99> 
  <M102>0</M102> 
  <M100>100</M100> 
 </Measures>
 <Measures>
  ------
  ------
 </Measures>
 <Measures>
  ------
  ------
 </Measures>
```

i want to my xml to be like this

i have tried to create an xslt file for converting, it did not work and i have seen many websites and videos, i could not make it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test%20schema%20from%20editor.xsd">
<Measures>
  <Project>SMFC4B0</Project> 
  <WorkProduct>Algo Integration Test</WorkProduct> 
  <Date>41725</Date> 
       <meashure>
          <name>M14</name>
          <value>100</value> 
       </meashure> 
       <meashure>
          <name>M99</name>
          <value>10</value> 
       </meashure> 
       <meashure>
          <name>M102</name>
          <value>0</value> 
       </meashure> 
       <meashure>
          <name>M100</name>
          <value>100</value> 
       </meashure>  
</Measures>
<Measures>
 <Project>ARS 400</Project> 
  <WorkProduct>System Test</WorkProduct> 
  <Date>41725</Date> 
       <meashure>
          <name>M14</name>
          <value>100</value> 
       </meashure> 
       <meashure>
          <name>M99</name>
          <value>10</value> 
       </meashure> 
       <meashure>
          <name>M102</name>
          <value>0</value> 
       </meashure> 
       <meashure>
          <name>M100</name>
          <value>100</value> 
       </meashure> 
 </Measures>
```

i want the xslt file to create this output.

Please can anyone provide me the xslt file. or some useful material to write this xslt script.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Can you also explain the logic of the transformation. For example, what makes `M14` and `M99` classed as "measures". How would you distinguish them from other elements, such as `Date` and `WorkProduct`? Thanks.

Comment: @TimC It is surely up to you, but I am not sure why you'd want to answer "do my work for me" question.

Comment: @lexicore You're right, as the question is now, it is pretty unanswerable - but Tim is by far the nicest person in the XSLT corner. Still, also voting to close.

Comment: Hai, Sorry for the late reply. Actually these values are metrics taken from DOORS tool for requirements management purpose. It’s actually collected every week from doors. If i take the output today the project, date and work product will be the unique primary values for all the weeks and only the metrics value will change every week. So i want to combine them to measures like m14, m99, m100 and so on.....with there corresponding values.....i hope i made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

try this one out

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Root>
      <xsl:for-each select="Root/Measures">
        <Measures>
          <Project>
            <xsl:value-of select="Project"/>
          </Project>
          <WorkProduct>
            <xsl:value-of select="WorkProduct"/>
          </WorkProduct>
          <Date>
            <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
          </Date>
          <xsl:variable name="temp" select="Date/following-sibling::*"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="$temp">
            <meashure>
              <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
              </name>
              <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </value>
            </meashure>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Measures>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>
```